# Rules of java 17 in sonarQube 9.8

Tags: sonarqube, java-17

I upgraded SonarQube to version 9.8 and java 17.

I've a configure profile of my company.
Now I want to add the rules of java 17 from sonar 9.8 to my profile.

There is a way to filter the build-in rules that related to java 17?
Or do you have a list of that?

Thanks ahead